# cascade delete com entity framework

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

estou com a seguinte situação:
meu banco de dados é MySql, quando tento excluir um registro direto no banco, da essa mensagem:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lifeproject`.`t0041_usuario`, CONSTRAINT `fk_t0041_usuario_t0040_grupo_usuario1` FOREIGN KEY (`t0040_id_grupo`) REFERENCES `t0040_grupo_usuario` (`t0040_id_grupo`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

ok, esta correto, é isso mesmo que preciso, porem, quando tento deletar pela aplicação, nao é respeitado o On Delete restrict, que esta setado na criação da tabela. Estou usando Entity Framewrok 6. Entendo que ao tentar excluir pela aplicação, o Mysql deveria disparar a mesma exceção  de restrição para a aplicação. Alguem pode me dar um auxilio?

aqui esta a classe grupoUsuarios

```
[Table("t0040_grupo_usuario")]
public class GrupoUsuarioModel
{
    #region propriedades
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string t0040_id_grupo { get; set; }

    [Required]              
    public string  t0040_descricao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int t0020_id_empresa { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("t0020_id_empresa")]
    public virtual EmpresaModel EmpresaModel { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioModel> UsuarioModel { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<AcessoModel> AcessoModel { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

}

aqui esta a classe usuarios

```
 [Table("t0041_usuario")]
public class UsuarioModel
{
    #region propriedades       
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int t0041_id_usuario { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string t0041_nome_usuario { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public string t0040_id_grupo { get; set; }       

    [Required]
    public string t0041_descricao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string t0041_senha { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int t0020_id_empresa { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("t0020_id_empresa")]
    public virtual EmpresaModel EmpresaModel { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("t0040_id_grupo")]
    public virtual GrupoUsuarioModel GrupoUsuarioModel { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Não entendi. Pelo MySQL ele te da a mensagem, mas pelo sistema (EF) não?

Comment: Isso mesmo, pelo sistema(EF) não dá a mensagem e apaga o registro e suas dependências

Comment: Precisava dessa informação para entender melhor seu problema. Espero que a resposta lhe ajude.

Answer (score 1):

O Entity Framework utiliza algumas [convenções](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions(v=vs.113).aspx) em sua estrutura. O `Cascade Delete` é uma delas.

Existe algumas formas de remover esta convenção. A primeira, e mais simples, é no próprio contexto `DbContext`, onde você pode adicionar o seguinte código:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Dessa forma, estamos falando para remover a convenção de `Cascade Delete` nos relacionamentos de **OneToMany**, ou **1:N**.

Existem outras opções, como o `ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention`, 
por exemplo.

Uma outra forma, se estiver usando **Fluent Api** do Enfity Framework, é fazer a anotação no arquivo de configuração, desta forma:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<>(GrupoUsuarioModel)
            .HasOptional(p => p.UsuarioModel)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);//true para adicionar
```

Lembrando que caso utilize desta forma, deverá realizar a configuração em cada mapeamento.

[Este artigo](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s04.html) explica um pouco mais sobre isso, inclusive a opção no banco de dados (Sql Server).

Outro ponto que vale ressaltar é que existem diversas convenções, como a `PluralizingTableNameConvention`, que é responsável por "pluralizar" o nome das tabelas, geralmente adicionando o sufixo `es` nas tabelas.

Veja a lista completa [na documentação oficial.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions(v=vs.113).aspx)