# Entity deletar tabela e seus relacionamentos

Tags: c#, entity-framework

existe alguma forma de deletar um registro da tabela e todos os seus relacionamentos de uma vez? pois atualmente eu deleto cada registro relacionado antes de deletar o registro principal, e isso toma muito tempo, por exemplo tenho a tabela Nota e quero deletar um registro dela, porém antes preciso deletar um registro na tabela ItemNota que esta relacionado com a tabela Nota, para só depois deletar o registro da tabela Nota, existe alguma boa maneira de se fazer isso?

Comment: Veja [se esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/131228/20615) é o que você busca. Caso não seja, tente explicar um pouco mais o seu problema para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: qual é o banco de dados, isso tem que ser feito no banco e configurar no ORM para que ele saiba, apesar do que isso fica em responsabilidade do banco de dados é a melhor maneira se quiser deletar a cascata de registro.

Comment: Utilizamos SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você precisa é ativar a exclusão em cascata. Acredito que vocês estejam fazendo algo assim:

```
Nota.ItemsNotas.Clear();
Context.Entry(Nota).State = EntityState.Deleted;
Context.SaveChanges();
```

O Entity Framework (6) utiliza automaticamente algumas convenções para exclusão em cascata. Normalmente essas convenções são retiradas para que o programador adicione onde ele quer que ocorra:

```
//Não vai permitir que campos REQUIRED sofra Cascade Delete.
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Remover essas convenções é interessante porque não é sempre que você quer que ocorra Cascade DELETE.

Para ativar ela em apenas um relacionamento (no seu caso Nota e ItemNota) você precisa configurar Notas para:

```
HasMany(e => e.ItemNotas)
    .WithRequired(e => e.Nota)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.NotaId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Vale lembrar que só existe essa convenção para FluentAPI, não existe por padrão uma maneira de fazer por Data Annotation.

Caso você utilize migration, apenas rodar o migration e  atualize seu banco e vai gerar algo como:

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Nota", t => t.NotaId, cascadeDelete: true)
```

Caso contrário, é necessário fazer o alter table também para que isso funcione:

```
ALTER TABLE "TABELA" MODIFY CONSTRAINT ... ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Ai você altera os nomes de acordo com suas tabelas.